# Altering Create New account tab link in user login page

Tags: theming, routes

I tried using form alter for menu of tabs in /user page, that shows

"create new account", "login", request password

is it possible for us to alter the link so that the create new account can go to "customlink" instead of "user/register"

in drupal 7?

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to change the call back function of that menu item:

```
function MY_MODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user/register']['page callback'] = 'my_custom_function';
}
```

And then you could redirect to a new page in the callback:

```
function my_custom_function() {
  drupal_goto('customlink');
}
```

Comment: Even more succinct: `$items['user/register']['page callback'] = 'drupal_goto'; $items['user/register']['page arguments'] = array('customlink');`

Comment: Yeah - that makes more sense...

Comment: the 1st one works thank you!!! for the 2nd one, that needs to go into the hook menu then.. both works great though thank you!